# perl How to replace one occurence of a character with two

Tags: perl, character, substitution

I would like to translate all instances of a character with two characters.  The usual way I would do it is:

```
$text =~ s/a/aa/g;
```

I only want single instances of a character to be doubled.  So `aa` would remain `aa` and not turn into `aaaa`.

I am thinking I have to use variables in the `s///` statement but I cannot find any suitable pattern here or on the net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match instances of `a` that are not next to another `a`:

```
s/(?<!a)a(?!a)/aa/g;
```

Comment: "I only want single instances of a character to be doubled.", so what was your first solution doesn't work. `aa` will become `aaa` because the pattern matches the second `a`. I removed it for you. (Changed the wording a bit too since neither `a` in `aa` is enclosed by `a`s.)